# How to add a `nice` switch to my bash script

Tags: bash, scheduling, jobs, nice

I have a bash script which runs some jobs. Sometimes I want to be able to run those jobs with `nice` to lower their priority on a server.

For example, if my executable is `a.out`, I can run from the terminal `nice a.out` to lower the job priority.

In my bash script I have a variable `NICE`. I do one of the following 2 things:

```
# either nice is set
NICE="nice"

# or it is left unset
NICE=""
```

I then run my job using

```
"$NICE$ ./a.out
```

later in the script.

This works when `NICE="nice"` however does not work when `NICE` is left set to `NICE=""`.

One way around this is to use an if statement:

```
if [ "$NICE" == "nice" ]
then
    nice ./a.out
else
    ./a.out
fi
```

But this becomes 5 or 6 lines of code rather than just a single line.

Is it possible to accomplish what I was attempting using `NICE` as a variable to launch an executable with niceness or no niceness?

Comment: Remove the quotes: `$NICE ./a.out`

Comment: or simply put `#renice -10 $$` at the beginning of script, so you can remove the trailing `#` any time.

Comment: I doubt `"$NICE$ ./a.out` "works".

Answer (score 2):

Your first guess is *almost* right.

From the Bash man page (emphasis mine):

> Explicit null arguments ("" or '') are retained and passed to  commands
>     as empty strings.  Unquoted implicit null arguments, resulting from the
>     expansion of parameters that have no values, are removed.  **If a parameter
>     with  no  value  is expanded within double quotes, a null argument
>     results and is retained and passed to a command  as  an  empty  string.**
>     When  a  quoted null argument appears as part of a word whose expansion
>     is non-null, the null argument is removed.   That  is,  the  word  -d''
>     becomes -d after word splitting and null argument removal.

So for your case, you could simply drop the quotes:

```
$NICE ./a.out
```

which, depending on the value of `$NICE`, will expand to the following two-word command:

```
'nice' './a.out'
```

or a one-word command:

```
'./a.out'
```

You can use `set -x` to help debug this kind of expansion -- it prints the expanded word list so you can see if something has gone amiss.

Comment: `set -x` is a great tip